# Does it make sense to put a "min.js" fil in MVC Bundles?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, bundling-and-minification

When using `MVC` bundeling in `BundleConfig.cs`, the `.js` files is minified right?

So what if I use a `min.js`? Is it good or bad practice and why?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundlesJs/scroller").Include(
    //"~/Scripts/Common/scroller-dataTables.scroller.min.js" // .min version
    "~/Scripts/Common/scroller-dataTables.scroller.js") // not .min version
);
```

Comment: one can easily say the production file is minified and compressed to load fast. It is saving some  extra bits/KBs on the wire. that's it

Comment: An advantage of not using the non-minified file is that it aids in debugging scripts when in debug mode.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that was one thought I had too. So I could benefit from using non-min in dev, and switching all to .min version, in the bundeling, when releasing?

Comment: You don't really need to 'switch' to `.min` files because in production they will be minified automatically..

Comment: I found this good doc on subject: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: In release mode, the bundler *will* use the minified version, instead of minifying itself.

Answer (score 1):

`.min` means minified version of script file.
Minification isn't compression. It refers to the removal of whitespace and other nonessential characters like comments so that the code is still valid but as compact as possible.

As such, it is not recommended for development because it makes the code much less readable and much harder to edit.

> Minified code is still valid code in all respects and can be run
>   immediately.
>
> Minification happens anyway as part of the compilation process in most
>   languages. By pre-minifying the files, you simply speed up the
>   download and parsing process by a certain amount.